# Load and cache images with Javascript and know HTTP status code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, caching

I'm trying to **preload images** to remove those that would respond with a 404 or 500 HTTP status code. **I need to know what was the HTTP status code** and **I need the image to be cached**. Here's my problem:

1. If I use an `Image` or dummy `<img/>` tag, the image is cached but I cannot know the HTTP status code in the `onerror` callback.
2. If I use an XHR (`$.get` for jQuery or `$http.get` for angular), I get the status code but the image is not cached (the real `<img/>` will load the data again). I think I don't have control on the caching since this is a browser rule.

Is there a method that enables to have the HTTP status code and the image cached **by the browser**?

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of both by having  `onerror` trigger a request to get more details

```
var img= document.createElement('img');
img.src="....";

img.onerror = function(err){
   $.get(img.src).fail(xhr){
        //parse xhr details and do something with them      
   })
}
```

Note this will be subject to CORS restrictions for cross domain sources

Or if this is in a directive assigned to image element:

```
 link:function(scope, element){
    element[0].onerror = function(err){
       $.get(element[0].src).fail(xhr){
          //parse xhr details and do something with them      
       })
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sure, that works. So there's no way to do it in one call?

Comment: but why? You are only concerned about the ones that error.

Comment: Just trying to limit the number of calls to the server (some logic is performed before the image is served).

Comment: well `onerrror` doesn't provide the status. Only extra calls would be errors. If you are getting 500 errors those would be in your server error logs also.